# checking and unchecking radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Is there a way when a radio button from the top row is checked then all the bottom ones are unchecked, and vice versa? When the a radio button from the bottom row is selected then all the top ones are set to false

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <div id="base-1">
        Forward
        <form name="group_A" style="margin-top:5px">
            <input value="0" type="radio" name="button" checked/>
            <span> 0 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="1" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 1 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="2" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 2 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="3" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 3 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="base-2">
        Backward
        <form name="group_B" style="margin-top:5px">
            <input value="0" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 0 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="1" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 1 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="2" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 2 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="3" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 3 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
        </form>
    </div>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. This can be done very easily with jQuery. Here's a script that unchecks all other radio buttons in the document with the same `name` attribute.

This works by binding an event to all radio buttons' `change` event. This event will check if the radio button is being changed to `checked`, and if so, it will search the body for all other radio buttons with the same `name` attribute and change their `checked` property to false using `.prop()`.

```js
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){

  if($(this).prop("checked"))
  {
    $("body").find("input[type=radio][name="+$(this).attr("name")+"]").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<div id="base-1">
        Forward
        <form name="group_A" style="margin-top:5px">
            <input value="0" type="radio" name="button" checked/>
            <span> 0 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="1" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 1 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="2" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 2 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="3" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 3 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="base-2">
        Backward
        <form name="group_B" style="margin-top:5px">
            <input value="0" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 0 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="1" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 1 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="2" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 2 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
            <input value="3" type="radio" name="button"/>
            <span> 3 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
        </form>
    </div>
    <h3>This one shouldn't change</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="otherbutton">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was a bit  confused cause I was reading that radio buttons groups always have one checked. I must have got it wrong i guess....

Comment: Normally they do, but you can override the default behavior with javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery, this can be done with a few lines.

```
$('#base-2 input').click(function() {
   $('#base-1 input').prop('checked', false)
})

$('#base-1 input').click(function() {
   $('#base-2 input').prop('checked', false)
})
```

Also, I would recommend moving your content out of the `head` and into the `body`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

After cleaning up the code, I would use two different JavaScript onclick functions to give the desired outcome.  In the clean up of the code, we need to identify each radio button obj with a unique id.  We also need to put the code into the body of the html not the head.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Title</title>        
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="base-1">
                    Forward
                    <form name="group_A" style="margin-top:5px">
                        <input value="0" type="radio" id="btnTop0" name="btnTop0"  onclick="uncheckBottom()" checked />
                        <span> 0 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                        <input value="1" type="radio" id="btnTop1" name="btnTop1"  onclick="uncheckBottom()" />
                        <span> 1 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                        <input value="2" type="radio" id="btnTop2" name="btnTop2"  onclick="uncheckBottom()"  />
                        <span> 2 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                        <input value="3" type="radio" id="btnTop3" name="btnTop3"   onclick="uncheckBottom()" />
                        <span> 3 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div id="base-2">
                    Backward
                    <form name="group_B" style="margin-top:5px">
                        <input value="0" type="radio" id="btnBottom0" name="btnBottom0" onclick="uncheckTop()"/>
                        <span> 0 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                        <input value="1" type="radio" id="btnBottom1" name="btnBottom1" onclick="uncheckTop()"/>
                        <span> 1 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                        <input value="2" type="radio" id="btnBottom2" name="btnBottom2" onclick="uncheckTop()"/>
                        <span> 2 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                        <input value="3" type="radio" id="btnBottom3" name="btnBottom3" onclick="uncheckTop()"/>
                        <span> 3 &nbsp &nbsp</span>
                    </form>
                </div>

            <script>
             function uncheckBottom(){
                  document.getElementById("btnBottom0").checked = false;
                  document.getElementById("btnBottom1").checked = false;
                  document.getElementById("btnBottom2").checked = false;
                  document.getElementById("btnBottom3").checked = false;
             }

             function uncheckTop(){
                  document.getElementById("btnTop0").checked = false;
                  document.getElementById("btnTop1").checked = false;
                  document.getElementById("btnTop2").checked = false;
                  document.getElementById("btnTop3").checked = false;
             }
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could accept all three answers. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Remember, if you go with jquery, you’ll need to reference the jquery library through either a CDN or locally. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp